# json returns corrupted data

Tags: php, mysql, json, character-encoding

I am playing with an api that just reads from my database and returns the data in json format.

In phpMyAdmin the sentences are perfect (I used utf8_general to input a csv). Example:

```
    A line that uses 'r and special chars etc
```

But when I echo the json, I get this:

```
    A line that uses ///\\/\/\/r and special chars etc
```

First I got null object back so I used:

```
   mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

But I still get the corrupted data back.

**Update:**

Some more info:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

/* grab the posts from the db */
$query = "SELECT * FROM huren WHERE 1";

$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

// check row count 
$amount = mysql_num_rows($result);

/* create one master array of the records */
$houses = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $houses[] = $post;
    }
}

/* output in necessary format */

    header('Content-type: application/json');
 $changed_json= str_replace('\\/', '/',json_encode(array('House'=>$houses)));
echo str_replace('\\\\', '\\',$changed_json);
```

Comment: Heh, your SQL query is kind of amusing to read as a German ("huren" means "whores" in German)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's with the replacing operations? `json_encode` either returns fully valid JSON representing the exact input you gave it, or it returns `NULL` because there were issues like your data not being in UTF-8. You should not do anything to the string returned by `json_encode`! If you didn't get `NULL`, then you have won and just need to echo it.

It will just work with this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('House'=>$houses));
```

The charset doesn't really matter, since by default, `json_encode` produces pure ASCII output. This is because by default, unicode characters are represented in unicode escape sequences, e.g. `\uxxxx`

Comment: because if i don't do that its even worse i get this in some attributes: http:\/\somesite.com/\/\example

Comment: @user1876006 [yes, that's valid](http://www.json.org/string.gif). When you decode the json, it will become `http://somesite.com/example` again. The reason for this is default security against xss when echoing json inside embedded script element on a html page. Don't look at the encoded json, because you will never use that. You need to look at the result after you decode the json.

Comment: omg i thought "shut up", but after you explained it and i tried it, everything works! i decode the json in xcode so it was not necessary to fix that... thanks for the tip!! you solved 3 problems lol

Answer (score 0):

Give us a little more to go on, please.  Can you show us the part that encodes the string?

This seems to work by itself, so there must be some complex interaction from elsewhere.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_foo.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

$str = <<<END
A line that uses 'r and special chars etc
END;

$jso = json_encode($str);
$new = json_decode($jso);

// THESE SHOULD MATCH
var_dump($str);
var_dump($new);

echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump($jso);
```

Comment: Hi Ray. Welcome to SO! I used to be a pig EE contributor myself. Just to give you a heads-up. I question like this would be more appropriate  as a comment to the original post, instead of as a possible answer.